# Probability Question ~Beta(1,2)

Tags: probability

In the next hour, child C will
a) play video games for 40 minutes, and
b) watch TV for 20 minutes,
but not necessarily in that order (order could be a and then b, or b then a)
The two orders are equally possible.

The child's mother will call the child C at some random time t into the hour 0 <= t <= 1 ("the next hour" mentioned above starts at t=0, and t is measured in hours.)
This time variable has a ~beta(1,2) distribution.

What is the probability that child C will watch TV when his/her mother calls?

My thought was to calculate the expectation for beta distribution. 1 / (1 + 2)

expectation is 1/3 - mother is expected to call when t = 20 (time = 20 minutes)

Based on given info, child will either:

a) play video games 0 <= t <= 40 and then watch TV 40 <= t <= 60

b) watch TV 0 <= t <= 20 and then play video games 20 <= t <= 60

If mother calls at 20 minutes (expectation), then probability of child watching TV when mother calls is 0 since the child C will be playing video games in both cases.

Have i taken the correct approach with this question? I am not convinced / comfortable with my answer.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem areas are t=20 and t=40.  In situation a, the child is playing video games and watching tv when t = 40, and in situation b, the child is playing video games and watching tv when t = 20.

So, we either need to set the problem up with a) TV: $0\le t<40$ or $0\le t\le40$, Games: $40\le t\le60$ or $40<t\le60$ and similarly for b, or we let him be doing two things at once when $t=20$ or $t=40$.

If we accept two simultaneous activities, then, when his mother calls (at exactly 20 minutes), it will be a 50% chance that he is watching TV, and a 100% chance that he will be playing video games.

If we don't allow the overlap, and reword the problem, then it will depend on where the strict inequality is.